# Merging tables with condition on powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

Well, first of all, I'm new to PowerQuery so I'll try to throw as much info as possible here.

**I'm using Office 2019 Home and Business**

I have several tables taken from an internet site. I grouped them all in the group named "ANOS" (which means Years).
Some queries are in error as they will only be available in the corresponding years.

Group:
[image]

Every table look like this:
[image]

I would like to merge these queries into a new one conditionally. I got to this point with the query I created for the merge named "INDICE_MESCLA"

It has the following formula in the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    currentYear = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
    tableList = List.Transform({2011..currentYear}, each Number.ToText(_)),
    allTables = List.Transform(tableList, each #"ANOS"),
    combinedTable = Table.Combine(allTables)
in
    combinedTable
```

Steps:
[image]
[image]

I'm having error in steps "allTables" and "combinedTable" and I don't know how to solve.

Error on step "allTables"

*Expression.Error: The name 'ANOS' was not recognized. Make sure it is spelled correctly.*

Error on step "combinedTables"

*Expression.Error: ANOS import does not match any exports. Did you miss any module references?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANOS has nothing to do with the combine. Each table is still named **20xx**

```
let
currentYear = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
tableList = List.Transform({2011..currentYear}, each Number.ToText(_)),
combinedTable=Table.Combine(List.Transform(tableList, each Record.Field(Record.SelectFields(#shared,{_}),_)))
in
combinedTable
```

Comment: Didnt work, got error:

`Expression.Error: We were unable to convert the value "2011" to type Table.
Details:
    Value=2011
    Type=[Type]`

Comment: My bad. I forgot you have to kill yourself to indirectly reference numerical table.  The exact syntax escapes me, but this cludge works