# Merging tables with condition on powerquery - Wait for Table in web

Tags: excel, powerquery

I asked this question a while ago and got an answer that suited me:

[Merging tables with condition on powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770280/merging-tables-with-condition-on-powerquery)

However, I have a problem, my current code combines the year tables correctly, but at the beginning of the year on the first day the code will try to merge with the 2024 table for example, but it will not be available in the first days of the year, so I would like that the code would only use the table if it is available, for example we are on 01/01/2025 so the code will wait for the table from the year 2025, here is my current code:

```
let
currentYear = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
tableList = List.Transform({2011..currentYear}, each "INCC_" & Text.From(_)),
combinedTable=Table.Combine(List.Transform(tableList, each Record.Field(Record.SelectFields(#shared,{_}),_)))
in
combinedTable
```

Tables that the code combines:

[image]

Code from one of the tables, note that Data and Fonte adds +1 as the year progresses:

```
let
    Fonte = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://indiceseconomicos.secovi.com.br/indicadormensal.php?idindicador=59")),
    Data29 = Fonte{29}[Data],
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data29,{{"Header", type text}, {"Mês", type text}, {"índice", type number}, {"Var% Mês", Percentage.Type}, {"Acum. Ano%", Percentage.Type}, {"Acum. 12 meses%", Percentage.Type}})
in
    #"Tipo Alterado"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a new step `tableListWithRows`. See if that helps.

```
let
currentYear = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
tableList = List.Transform({2011..currentYear}, each "INCC_" & Text.From(_)),
tableListWithRows = List.Select(tableList, each try Table.RowCount(Record.Field(#shared,_)) > 0 otherwise false),
combinedTable = Table.Combine(List.Transform(tableListWithRows, each Record.Field(Record.SelectFields(#shared,{_}),_)))
in
combinedTable
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking your answer as correct, I was away from my work computer for a while. It worked perfectly, I did a test to prove it by adding `= List.Transform({2011..2025}, each "INCC_" & Text.From(_))` and the tableListWithRows only listed up to 2024 because 2025 was not available , as per my request, I thank you my friend!